# Undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass for object collection

Tags: ruby

Here is my code:

```
class Train
  attr_accessor :id, :person_id, :movie_id, :eval
  def initialize(id, person_id, movie_id, eval)
    @id = id
    @person_id = person_id
    @movie_id = movie_id
    @eval = eval
  end
end

trains = Array.new
CSV.open('train.csv', encoding: "BOM|UTF-16LE:UTF-8", row_sep: :auto, col_sep: ';') do    |csv|
  csv.each do |id, person_id, movie_id, eval|
    trains[id.to_i] = Train.new(id.to_i, person_id.to_i, movie_id.to_i, eval.to_i)
  end
end

trains.each do |t|
  puts t.id
end
```

It is just creating an array of objects from a CSV file, and printing the object's IDs, but I am getting an error:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

Why is `t` nil when I use `puts t` it is printing objects.

Comment: Ok, I found it, first element (trains[0]) is nil ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [the help for formatting your text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). The easier it is to read and understand, the faster and better we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're initializing the array but then adding to the trains array by specifying the index. If the id from your csv starts from 1 (or 101) then indexes 0 through your first will be initialized to nil.

Try using `trains <<` instead of `trains[id.to_i]` to populate the array.

Edit:

Given your comment, I'd recommend using hashes instead. They're still enumerable but in this way you can iterate freely and use the id as an accessible index (key).

```
trains = Hash.new
CSV.open('train.csv', encoding: "BOM|UTF-16LE:UTF-8", row_sep: :auto, col_sep: ';') do |csv|
  csv.each do |id, person_id, movie_id, eval|
    trains[id.to_i] = Train.new(id.to_i, person_id.to_i, movie_id.to_i, eval.to_i)
  end
end
```

So now you have a hash of the trains with the Train IDs as keys. Accessing it would still look like an array but it would return the object. Thus `trains[5]` would return the `Train` object with id of 5.

I think that's a better solution than using an array with a bunch of nils. However, if you're going to for some reason, just use a post conditional in your iteration (though this is really awkward):

```
trains.each do |t|
  puts t.id if t
end
```

In Ruby, only false and nil are "falsey" meaning evaluate to false so this will get you what you want. But for convenience, I'd really recommend going the Hash route.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I gave in the comment, I found that first element is nil. Your solution could be good, but I want to use ids for selecting each of trains, for example if I want to get one with id 5 I just use trains[5]. In your solution it will not work this way. Anyway, thanks for help. :)

Comment: I have edited the answer to give you a different type to use for storage that accomplishes your goal of indexing with the ID. A hash would be a far better use here.

Comment: Yeah, it is true, hash would be much better in most of the cases, in my situation I need array, but it is specific case.